# Ubuntu gave up waiting for root device, UUID does not exist, dropping to shell, when booting from a new kernel

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, kernel, initramfs

I have installed ubuntu 16.04(linux kernel 4.4.0.31) on my intel baytrail tablet. I am trying to install a different linux kernel (3.16.0). When I boot through the default kernel(4.4.0.31), the system boots properly but if I boot from 3.16.0 by selecting it from grub menu, the system doesn't boot. It throws error message :

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
  — Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    — Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
    — Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
  — Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=afc74186-1501-4498-ba4d-acd74df10923 does not exist.   
Dropping to a shell! 

BusyBox v.1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)   
Enter 'help' for list of built-in commands.  

(initramfs)
```

Running **blkid** from initramfs shell has no output. Also there is no **/dev/disk/by-uuid** folder in the file system.

Since I can boot from the default kernel 4.4.0.31, I compared the contents of **/etc/fstab** and **ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid** and both are matching.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

1. Boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-USB then choose "Try Ubuntu"
2. Connect to the Internet
3. Open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter
       after each line):

   ```
       sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
       sudo apt-get update
       sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
   ```

   This installs and runs Boot-Repair. Click "Recommended repair".
   After it has done its magic, write down the URL
   (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and
   check if you recovered access to your OSs and can boot normally
   /without dropping to shell/.
4. If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who may
   help you by email or forum. You can also review it yourself and look
   over possible errors.
   Some people also report boot problems after new installation liveusb from USB 3.0 drive. Use old usb 2.0 drive or DVD if available.